# Pairwise operations in Scikit-Learn and different filtering conditions on each pair

Tags: scikit-learn, pairwise

I have the following 2 data frames, say df1

```
    a   b   c   d
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   0   0   7
2   8   9  10  11
3   0   0  0  15
```

and df2

```
    a   b   c   d
0   5   1   2   3
```

What I am interested in doing is a pairwise operation on each row in df1 with the single row in df2.  However, if a column in a row of df1 is 0, then that column is used in neither the df1 row nor df2 row to perform the pairwise operation.  So each pairwise operation will work on pairs of rows of different length.  Let me break it down how the 4 comparison should be.

Comparison 1

0 1 2 3 vs 5 1 2 3
The pairwise operation is done on 1 2 3 vs 1 2 3 as column a has a 0

Comparison 2

4 0 0 7 vs 5 1 2 3 is done on 4 7 vs 5 3 as we have 2 columns that need to be dropped

Comparison 3

8 9 10 11 vs 5 1 2 3 is done on 8 9 10 11 vs 5 1 2 3 as no columns are dropped

Comparison 4

0 0 0 15 vs 5 1 2 3 is done on 15 vs 3 as all but one column is dropped

The result of each pairwise operation is a scalar so the result is some sort of structure whether it be list, array, data frame, whatever with 4 (or the number of rows in df1) values.  Also, I should note that values in df2 are irrelevant and no filtering is done based upon the value of any column in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, you could try looping over each row in the dataframe and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,1,2,3],[4,0,0,7],[8,9,10,11],[0,0,0,15]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
b = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# loop over each row in 'a'
for i in range(len(a)):
    # find indicies of non-zero elements of the row
    non_zero = np.nonzero(a.iloc[i].to_numpy())[0]

   # perform pair-wise addition between non-zero elements in 'a' and the same elements in 'b'
    print(np.array(a.iloc[i])[(non_zero)] +  np.array(b.iloc[0])[(non_zero)])
```

Here I used pair-wise addition but you could replace the addition with an operation of your choosing.

**Edit:**
We may want to vectorize this to avoid the loop if the dataframes are large. Here is an idea for that, where we convert zero values to nan so they are ignored in the row-wise operation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0,1,2,3],[4,0,0,7],[8,9,10,11],[0,0,0,15]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
b = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 1, 2, 3]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# find indicies of zeros
zeros = (a==0).values

# set zeros to nan
a[zeros] = np.nan

# tile and reshape 'b' so its the same shape as 'a'
b = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(b, len(a)).reshape(np.shape(a)), columns=b.columns)
# set the zero indices to nan
b[zeros] = np.nan

print('a:')
print(a)

print('b:')
print(b)

# now do some row-wise operation. For example take the sum of each row
print(np.sum(a+b, axis=1))
```

**Output:**

```
a:
     a    b     c   d
0  NaN  1.0   2.0   3
1  4.0  NaN   NaN   7
2  8.0  9.0  10.0  11
3  NaN  NaN   NaN  15
b:
     a    b    c  d
0  NaN  1.0  2.0  3
1  5.0  NaN  NaN  3
2  5.0  1.0  2.0  3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  3
sum:
0    12.0
1    19.0
2    49.0
3    18.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: So it works, that is for sure, and thank you for that as I will study the two lines in the for loop for understanding.  I have tried it out and get the answers I expect.  I will upvote, however I would ask does this answer scale?  Suppose instead of 4 rows, what if I have 10,000 rows?  I was trying to avoid a for loop in my previous attempts, but if necessary, is necessary.

Comment: We can vectorize the operation using numpy. Give me a second to work on it.

Comment: I edited the answer to show one idea for avoiding loops

Comment: Thanks, probably won't get back to it until Monday, but will let you know how the timing turns out.  The initial for loop way is painful, but it can complete, so hopefully this will be more what I am looking for

Comment: Yes, so I noticed the speed difference.  That is great, not worth documenting because it is what one would expect from for loop to vectorization.  It is a little bit harder to spot if all the values are right (I do an argsort to get the indices of the greatest value) but the results are believable so I think this general approach does work for me.